# Drag gesture recognition is inconsistent

Tags: swiftui, gesture

Note: this seems like a solved problem and I may not be using the right keywords to surface the answer.

I have an object for a dynamically editable
[textballoon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wXDq.png)

These are imbedded in a document based app restricted to IOS16+ and are meant to behave similarly to the same type of object in Apple's FreeForm.App.

Below a certain size, I cannot consistently get the system (13" iPad Pro) to recognize a drag gesture on any of the points with a finger touch (but I can using a mouse pointer).

The drag points on the object (the blue and green circles with light blue squares around them) have the following a code:

```
    func dragPoint(isChanging: Bool, isVisible: Bool, inFrame size: CGFloat, atOffset offset: CGSize, color: Color) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .fill(isChanging ? .yellow : color)
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : 0)

            Rectangle()
                .fill(isChanging ? .blue : .blue)
                .frame(width: 3 * size, height: 3 * size)
                .opacity(isVisible ? 0.2 : 0.2)
        }
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .offset(offset)
    }
```

Things I have tried so far:
Making the drop targets larger helps but past a certain size the overlap with nearby dragPoints becomes problematic.
All other gestures are masked when the object is editable.
ContentShape (though think that's redundant to the rectangle in the Stack)

Comment: This needs a [mre] to be debuggable